# I installed React, then I get a typo when I save it

Tags: javascript

I have provided all the necessary institutions for React.
Afterwards, when I ctrl s the codes, the js codes try to resemble the js syntax. I am getting the below issue?
What can I do?

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    return ( <
        div className = "App" >
        <
        header className = "App-header" >
        <
        img src = { logo }
        className = "App-logo"
        alt = "logo" / >
        <
        p >
        Edit < code > src / App.js < /code> and save to reload. <
        /p> <
        a className = "App-link"
        href = "https://reactjs.org"
        target = "_blank"
        rel = "noopener noreferrer" >
        Learn React <
        /a> <
        /header> <
        /div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's with all those new lines between `<` and `>`? Use `<code>` not `< code >`

Comment: That's what happens when you use the "tidy" function on React snippets and other code "tidiers" @evolutionxbox.

Comment: It looks like your code auto-formatter does not support or is not configured to recognize JSX.

Comment: May you share what the error you're seeing is?

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's causing a problem.

This is the result from the terminal.

Compiled successfully!

You can now view kurulum in the browser.

Local: http://localhost:3000
On Your Network: http://192.168.254.76:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized. To create a production build, use npm run build.

Comment: Do you have a answer my problem? By the way,  Where Can I add tidiers? Powershell or VS Code and How?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `Prettier code formatter` and `vs-code`, open the settings and search `jsx`, then configure them like below.

[image]

Comment: But I dont know. How can i do? Can you to describe ?Please.

Comment: Yes, I am using

Comment: I did but it is not be okey again.

Comment: I also did the formatting from this site.             https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/code-formatting-with-prettier-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: just search `jsx` in `settings` and then change the configurations like given in the image (_in the answer_).

Comment: Yeah I did but it is not okey again.

Comment: Hey! Do you have other answer about my question?If you help i'll be happy really

Comment: I am  new here. I tried to add photo at up. Can you control please..

Comment: if you save again your codes that should work, for more  [info](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)

Comment: No I am really sad. It is not work again. The Syntax is giving mistake.

Comment: Actually, I am not getting syntax error. Just, When ı save my codes then at vs code is getting syntax error as above.I mean it is not different nothing. it is same.